# Can't type properly use AltGr after updating to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters

Before updating to Ubuntu 20.04 my AltGr key used to work as expected. My Keyboard layout is portuguese (brazil) abnt2. I use AltGr specially to type things like º

Now, if I just press AltGr a weird character that looks like an arrow appear (I tried to print screen it but it disappears when I press any other key)

Does anyone has a clue of what is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I just fixed it just by installing gnome tweaks tool and disabling the `compose key` under `keyboard & mouse`. Now I can use special characters like © or ª º

Comment: Out of curiosity: You had defined <AltGr> as the compose key yourself, hadn't you?

Comment: Yes I had done that. When using ubuntu 18.04 my keyboard was note configured properly and I kind of messed up with the configuration.

Comment: Similar situation after installing Ubuntu 22.04. AltGr+2 prints @ in spanish keyboards. Had to disable `Right Alt never chooses 3rd level` within `Key to choose the 3rd level` in  Tweaks/Keyboard & Mouse/Additional Layout Options (requires gnome-tweaks package). Don't know why this option was enabled.